PHP Ebay API ReviseFixedPriceItem - add multiple pictures to multidimensional variants
I would like to automate the upload of product images via the Ebay API (ReviseFixedPriceItem).
As an example, let's take “screws” as an Ebay item. The selection options would be “thread size” and “length”. So for example a variant would be: [“Thread size” => “M8”, “Length” => 20 mm"].
Now I would like to assign 2 (or more) pictures to each individual variant, which I have already uploaded to eBay Picture Services (EPS). So I have the “PictureURL” of my pictures.
If I now look at the API documentation (https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/ReviseFixedPriceItem.html), the explanations are only given for one-dimensional cases (e.g. only “thread size”). I don't understand how I can assign several images to a multi-dimensional item.
    $variation = new VariationType("");
    $variation->setSKU($sku);

    $pictures = new PicturesType("");
    $pictures->setVariationSpecificName(???); // following the doc, this field is required - but with one should I insert? ("thread size" or "length")

    $variationSpecificPictureSet = new VariationSpecificPictureSetType("");
    $variationSpecificPictureSet->setVariationSpecificValue(); // which value should I insert? ("M8" or "20 mm")
    $variationSpecificPictureSet->setPictureURL($imageURLFromEPS);
    
    $pictures->setVariationSpecificPictureSet([$variationSpecificPictureSet]);

    $variations = new VariationsType("");
    $variations->setPictures([$pictures]); // here multiple images for one variation??
    $variations->setVariation([$variation]);

    $item->setVariations($variations);

I have reduced my code to the essentials to make it easier to understand where my comprehension problem lies.
Can anyone help me at this point? Thanks in advance for your help!

Looking here I found these methods:
    /**
     * Set PictureURL value
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     * @param string[] $pictureURL
     * @return \StructType\ExtendSiteHostedPicturesResponseType
     */
    public function setPictureURL(array $pictureURL = array())
    {
        // validation for constraint: array
        if ('' !== ($pictureURLArrayErrorMessage = self::validatePictureURLForArrayConstraintsFromSetPictureURL($pictureURL))) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException($pictureURLArrayErrorMessage, __LINE__);
        }
        $this->PictureURL = $pictureURL;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Add item to PictureURL value
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     * @param string $item
     * @return \StructType\ExtendSiteHostedPicturesResponseType
     */
    public function addToPictureURL($item)
    {
        // validation for constraint: itemType
        if (!is_string($item)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The PictureURL property can only contain items of type anyURI, %s given', is_object($item) ? get_class($item) : (is_array($item) ? implode(', ', $item) : gettype($item))), __LINE__);
        }
        $this->PictureURL[] = $item;
        return $this;
    }

which handle picture URLs by arrays and therefore support its plurality.
